# Checking a dictionary key name, which is an instance of a class

Tags: python, json

I am using a module called [jsondiff](https://pypi.org/project/jsondiff/) to compare changes between two json files. When a change is detected it returns a dictionary. The dictionary keys are instances of a class from the module.

Depending on the type of change (something new added, deleted or changed), the dictionary keys are named differently but appear to be an instance of the same class

I am trying to check if the instance is equal to a certain type of change. How can I write a conditional to check the name of the key?

Here is an example: json file 1

```
[{
    "first": "John",
    "last": "Smith",
    "membership": "general"
},
{
    "first": "Jane",
    "last": "Dogood",
    "membership": "VIP"
}]
```

json file 2

```
[{
    "first": "John",
    "last": "Smith",
    "membership": "VIP"
 },
 {
    "first": "Jane",
    "last": "Dogood",
    "membership": "VIP"
 },
 {
    "first": "Robert",
    "last": "Jones",
    "membership": "VIP"
 }]
```

Python code

```
with open("/file1.json") as f1, open("/file2.json") as f2:
    data1 = json.load(f1)
    data2 = json.load(f2)

changes = jsondiff.diff(data1, data2)

for key, val in changes.items():
    print(key, val)
    print(type(key))
    if key == "insert": # also tried "$insert", and insert without quotes
      # Do something
```

Output:

```
0 {'membership': 'VIP'}
<class 'int'>
$insert [(2, {'first': 'Robert', 'last': 'Jones', 'membership': 'VIP'})]
<class 'jsondiff.symbols.Symbol'>
```

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer, but I made it better. Maybe the new information will help you even more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `key` is of type `jsondiff.symbols.Symbol`, and you can check that directly.

```
    if key == jsondiff.symbols.insert:
        #do something
```

When the `key` is printed we know it returns `$insert`. This means it has a `str` representation. We can get that representation by wrapping the `key` in `str`.

```
    if str(key) == "$insert":
        #do something
```

[jsondiff.symbols.py](https://github.com/fzumstein/jsondiff/blob/master/jsondiff/symbols.py)

Comment: Wow! So simple! Thank you sir

Comment: You are welcome. I love these quickies. Make sure you look at that symbols script. You could potentially need to create a condition list based on the type of symbol returned, If so, the `jsondiff.symbols.__all__` and `jsondiff.symbols._all_symbols_` lists will be your friend.

Comment: You should use the first version if it's at all possible that a key might legitimately be `$insert`. In that case the second version comparing the string to `$insert` would give you a false positive.